# Adding custom images to leaflet - images not showing?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to add images to a custom marker in leaflet but my images are not showing on a map.

I would be grateful if somebody could please take a look at my javascript code below, and suggest what I need to change.

Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>


<title>Custom image</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>


<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var customicon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconUrl: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yek0JUpIDd4/maxresdefault.jpg',
        iconSize:     [38, 95],
        iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
        popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
    }
}).addTo(map);

var customicon2 = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconUrl: 'https://th.bing.com/th/id/R27dd55e9cf8e8da143fecd97ce458971?rik=KfMXOxgXTz4Ucw&pid=ImgRaw',
        iconSize:     [38, 95],
        iconAnchor:   [23, 95],
        popupAnchor:  [-3.5, -78]
        }
    }).addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do read https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/ .

Comment: All sorted, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The Leaflet Icon's do not do anything by themselves.

You have to feed them as `icon` option of a Leaflet Marker, as shown in the ["Markers with Custom Icons" Leaflet tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/)

```js
L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {
  icon: greenIcon
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Prenton Park</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>


    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>

    
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([53.375, -3.03], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var pp_icon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
//          shadowUrl: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yek0JUpIDd4/maxresdefault.jpg',
            iconSize:     [38, 95],
            shadowSize:   [50, 64],
            iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
            shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
        }
    });

    var prenton_park = new pp_icon({iconUrl: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yek0JUpIDd4/maxresdefault.jpg'});

    L.marker([53.375, -3.03], {icon: prenton_park}).bindPopup("I am Prenton Park.").addTo(map);

</script>



</body>
</html>
```